# How can I get a full working example with React 0.14 and Typescript 1.6.2 and Rails 4.2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Does anyone have a working example of the latest (stable) React, working with latest (stable) Typescript and Rails 4.2?

Using the typescript-rails gem (https://github.com/typescript-ruby/typescript-rails) and Rails 4.2 works just fine via the asset pipeline.

For instance, none of these examples work:
http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/07/05/using-jsx-react-with-typescript/
http://staxmanade.com/2015/08/playing-with-typescript-and-jsx/

The various errors encountered are: (based on which example, and which DefinitelyTyped react.d.ts's you're using from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped)

/var/folders/ng/f_1__7m57x9bmprw7lvpz7180000gn/T/typescript-node20151114-27510-1dvq95y.ts(18,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReactDOM'.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts - `ReactDOM` seems to be defined. Maybe you can just update your typings via [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).

Comment: For anyone looking for a nodejs aka `typescript` all the way, checkout : https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb Here's why you might want to use the same language : https://medium.com/@basarat/issues-with-polyglot-programming-8f9ba0bfcb47

Answer (score 4):

After a day I figured it out.

**Preparation**

Step 0.

Ensure that you correctly installed typescript-rails gem and verified it working with Rails 4.2 asset pipeline.  (See: https://github.com/typescript-ruby/typescript-rails)

Step 1.

There is a bug in typescript-rails (0.6.2) gem with the --jsx react.  To work around this, create a local copy of the gem files and save it to:

```
vendor/typescript-rails-0.6.2
```

and then tell your Rails app via the gemfile to include it directly:

```
gem 'typescript-rails',  :path => "vendor/typescript-rails-0.6.2"
```

Now, we modify the typescript-rails from:

```
# vendor/typescript-rails-0.6.2/lib/typescript/rails/compiler.rb
# 
# ... (line 69):
self.default_options = %w(--target ES5 --noImplicitAny)
# ....
#
```

To:

```
# vendor/typescript-rails-0.6.2/lib/typescript/rails/compiler.rb
# 
# ... (line 69):
self.default_options = %w(--target ES5 --jsx react)
# ....
#
```

Step 2.

Copy the following react files to your app/assets/javascript folder:

https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.js
   and...
   https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.js

Update your application.js to include these 2 react files:

```
 // app/assets/javascripts/application.js:
 // ...
 //= require react-0.14.2.js
 //= require react-dom-0.14.2.js
 // ...
```

Now we're done with initial setup (everything should still work with the changes above)

**Steps**

Step 0.

From https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react copy all files to app/assets/javascripts/typing (Critical step that I was missing from before)

Step 1. Create a file app/assets/javascript/home.ts  (to be loaded by the HomeController) with the contents:

```
/// <reference path="typing/react-global.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="my_component.tsx"/>
```

Step 2. Create a file app/assets/javascript/my_component.tsx with contents:

```
/// <reference path="./typing/react-global.d.ts" />

interface HelloWorldProps {
  name: string;
}

var HelloMessage = React.createClass<HelloWorldProps, any>({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var mountNode = document.getElementById('id_of_mount_dom_element');
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

Step 3.

Ensure you have a file home/index.html.erb file a React root div element with id 'id_of_mount_dom_element'.  Then you will see the component mount when loading the page (say http://127.0.0.1:3000/home)

```
Hello John
```

**Done**